# How To Set Image From Another Activity's String

Tags: android

I'm trying set Image from another activity's string.

My string on MainActivity

`public static String imagee;  // -- this is out of onCreate`

```
    capeMod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {

        MainActivity.imagee = "drawable/pc";
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ModActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);   

    }

    });
```

On another activity: (yeah, this is completely wrong.)

`String imagee = MainActivity.imagee;`

```
  private void showImage() {
  // int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
  int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(imagee, null, getPackageName());
  Drawable imagee = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
  image.setImageDrawable(image);
 }
```

I can set TextView from another activity's string but couldnt set ImageView.How can i solve issue?

Comment: does it really need to be a String? or an integer is okay?

Comment: No no, doesn't need to integer. Code on another activity can be change. I thing I found wrong code for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

assuming that you can access to the string value doing like you did with the static string, use resources:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String imageName= MainActivity.imagee;
int resID = res.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(resID );
image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

**EDIT: even if it works, the correct way to access a value is not through *static* way, is always better to go via *Intents* and *putExtra* :)**

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley it worked but using `static` variable to transfer data between activities is not right way. Because your static variable will not be free when activity get destroyed. You should use `Intent` to do that.

Comment: @mr.icetea oh, yes you're right, i wrote this code because he asked only for the way to set the image,. I didn't even know that you can use static to acces from other activities, i found it on the web :P Anyway i will add the note that is better to do elseway ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a String I suggest using the id (which is an int) directly

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

        Button capeMod = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capemod);
        capeMod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ModActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ModActivity.EXTRA_DRAWABLE_ID, R.drawable.pc);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ModActivity:

```
public class ModActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_DRAWABLE_ID = "drawableId";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout2);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int drawableId = bundle.getInt(EXTRA_DRAWABLE_ID);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Intent.putExtra()` to send data as well as `String`, and in other `Activity` use `Intent.getExtras()` to receive the data.  Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it. You need to place variable name as

```
imagee = "pc"; //inside drawable folder.

int resourceId = Activity.getResources().getIdentifier(imagee , "drawable", "your.package.name");   // package name can get by code also.

Drawable imagee = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

image.setImageDrawable(image);
```

Try this code that will work.